# Declarando uma string em C

Tags: c, string

Ao definir o tamanho de uma string e não usar todo o espaço na memória reservado, após o \0 o restante será liberado?

```
char nome[40] = "carlos";
```

No exemplo acima declaro uma string com tamanho 40, porem o conteúdo da variável só ocupa 6. Minha dúvida é se o restante da memória (33 bytes) reservada para string será liberada.

Comment: Podes não definir um tamanho:  char nome[] = "carlos";

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Primeiro, sem o contexto de onde esta declaração está fica complicado dar uma boa resposta. Se ela for global é uma coisa, se for local é outra. Vou considerar que é local, mas se for global não é assim que funciona.

A forma como declarou a variável irá ocupar 40 bytes sendo que 39 poderão ser usados para colocar caracteres (*strings* sempre precisam de 1 byte terminador). Isto é fixo não importa se você colocar menos. E se colocar mais nada irá impedir, vai corromper a memória.

Deve estar pensando que isto é desperdício, e de certa forma é, mas não é tanto quanto deve estar pensando. Como isto está em *stack* ([leia mais sobre](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101)) o espaço dele todo já está alocado quando começa executar, então não muda o consumo geral da aplicação, a única ocupação é que uma parte da pilha será reservada para esta variável e este espaço será de 40 bytes. Note que na compilação não alocará 40 bytes em lugar algum, só na execução da função isto ocorrerá.

Mas não é o único consumo. O texto `carlos\0` ocupará 7 bytes na execução (e ocupará espaço na memória quando o executável for carregado). Ele ficará em uma área chamada Data Segment. Quando for executar a função esse dado será copiado do Data Segment para o *stack*, então tem um custo de processamento (ao contrário que muita gente pensa em C tem processamentos escondidos em operações que parecem não ter).

Existe um ponto importante sobre isto que é o fato de você poder manipular o que está no *stack*. Pode por outro valor ali sem maiores custos (não precisa criar outra variável e copiar pra lá) e não passando de 39 caracteres não corrompe a memória, e isto é outro ponto importante.

Está desperdiçando 33 bytes? Eu não posso afirmar sem contexto, mas acho que não. Está preparado para trabalhar com até 39 caracteres e pode ser bem útil ter esse espaço extra, mesmo que acabe não usando sempre. Seria um desperdício se nunca usar mais que os 6 caracteres, nunca mudar esse valor para mais. Mesmo assim não é algo tão grave se não tiver isso muitas milhares de vezes. De fato programadores experientes fazem uso de uma reserva maior com muita frequência, inclusive porque a economia do espaço pode exigir o uso do *heap* (já deve ter lido sobre no *link* acima) que é muito mais complicado manipular. Tudo em computação é *tradeoff*, então as pessoas preferem ocupar um pouco mais de *stack* do que ter que alocar em um local caro e complicado.

Então esqueça esse desperdício se deseja ter espaço para colocar outro texto maior. E tem a vantagem de poder modificar seu conteúdo.

Se realmente está usando mais do que deveria para o seu problema então pode fazer assim:

```
char nome[] = "carlos";
```

Isto ocupará 7 bytes no Data Segment e 7 bytes no *stack* toda vez que executar a função que tem essa declaração. É melhor se você garante que o texto nunca passará de 6 caracteres.

Mas se ele nunca passará de 6 caracteres provavelmente ele nunca mudará, então para que copiar para o *stack*? Se você declarar assim:

```
char *nome = "carlos";
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/ArrayXPointer.c).

não fará uma cópia. A *string* fica só no Data Segment e `nome` será só um ponteiro indicando que o texto está no Data Segment. E você não pode mudar nada nela, nem tamanho, nem mesmo  mudar um caractere por outro. Esta é a forma mais econômica em espaço (ocupa nada no *stack*) e processamento, desde que você possa abrir mão de modificação dela.

É mais econômica na maioria dos casos, não nesse, embora dê quase no mesmo. Se você estiver usando uma arquitetura 64bits  haverá um ponteiro de 8 bytes no *stack* para apontar para o Data Segment, que é mais que os 7 bytes que o texto ocuparia. Ainda seria vantajoso pelo custo de cópia não existir.

Pra finalizar, um ponteiro não especifica tamanho da *string*, sua função é outra. Não declarar o tamanho sendo com *array* ou ponteiro, desde que o dado seja inicializado, fará com que o tamanho seja o mesmo da inicialização, ou seja, acontecerá uma inferência, e não desperdiçará nada (perdendo a flexibilidade de poder ter um texto maior), se é o que deseja.

Answer (score 0):

Uma vez declarado `char nome[40]` irá ser alocado 40 char na memoria no momento da compilação, esse valor não pode ser alterado, porém você pode utilizar um ponteiro para especificar o tamanho do vetor na declaração da variável.

```
char nome[40] = "carlos"; // 40 bytes
char *nome2 = "carlos"; // 6 bytes
```

Comment: "*esse valor não pode ser alterado*", ficou estranho; não posso alterar (re)alocando a memória?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss este meu exemplo foi num contexto estático, e até onde conheço C a maneira de realocar é usando o realloc() quando as variáveis foram declaradas usando malloc() o que não foi no meu caso. Se existe alguma maneira de realocar variáveis estaticamente alocadas eu não lembro no momento.

Comment: Vale mencionar que embora válidas, essas duas instruções não representam exatamente o mesmo. A string `nome` é alterável e você pode fazer algo como `nome[0] = 'M';` ao passo que o mesmo já não é correto para a string `nome2`. Em acrescimo a string `nome2` ocupa 7 bytes pois precisa na mesma do terminador

Answer (score -1):

Da maneira como você fez você está atribuindo à variável `nome` a variável `carlos`. Creio que não é o que você deseja.

Em C utiliza-se a função `strcpy`, de `<string.h>`, para copiar strings.  Estude sobre array e ponteiros para entender.

Para inicializar uma string você pode utilizar:

```
char nome[40] = "carlos";
```

---

A declaração acima reservará uma área de memória de 40 bytes, utilizará apenas 7 bytes desta área (existe um caractere terminador '\0' que indica o final da string) e o restante ficará reservado podendo ser utilizado em operações posteriores, por exemplo em uma concatenação.